# links to Facebook personal profiles do not always work

Tags: facebook, http, hyperlink, search-engine, privacy

My alumni website (a self-contained website with its own domain name that is not part of Facebook) contains many links to the personal profiles (Facebook screens that are for non-commercial use and represent individual people) of my high school classmates.  These links all work fine when my browser is currently logged into a Facebook account.  However, only some of them work when my browser is not logged into Facebook.  The ones that don't take me instead to a Facebook screen that says "Sorry, this page* isn't available" or "Sorry, this content isn't available right now."  Why?

*Since the screen that didn't load is technically NOT a Page, it is (technically speaking, anyway) a little misleading of Facebook to describe it as such on this screen that comes up.

[This updated version was prompted by luschn's answer which pointed out that my original question failed to distinguish between Pages and personal profiles.] Here is an explanation of the difference: https://www.facebook.com/help/217671661585622

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those Pages are most likely restricted by age or location, so you MUST be logged in on Facebook to access them. And you must be allowed to see them on Facebook. Else, Facebook does not know if you are old enough or in the correct location.

Of course it can also be a glitch, you should file a bug if that's the case. And finally, if you put those messages into google, you will find a large amount of results. For example: https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=820422994739769

Edit: There is a big difference between Pages and (User) Profiles, but since your question is about Pages, this is most likely the answer. You can change the visibility of your User Profile here: https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=privacy

Comment: You seem to be making the false claim that clicking a link to a personal FB page in a browser that is not logged into FB will not take you to that FB page.  Most of the links to my high school classmates' FB pages on our alumni website work fine even when my browser isn't logged into FB.  My best guess as to why this might be so, is because FB's default answer to the search engine question is "Yes" and most probably never bothered to change it.  We can also discuss whether there are age and location restrictions, but refuting your answer didn't require me to.

Comment: please read my answer again, i made it a bit more clear. make sure you understand the difference between pages and profiles. i am not making "false claims", it is a very well known issue with pages.

Comment: Think I finally figured out what your answer says.  In a nutshell, there are more ways than the one I cited (answering "No" to the search engine question) that can cause this same behavior: other answers to other questions in a person's FB settings also have the ability to cause their page to not load if a browser isn't logged into FB.  And unlike the search engine question, these other settings have the power to prevent the FB page from being visible to a browser even if it IS logged into FB, with the final determination being made by what the viewer's own FB profile contains.  Am I right?

Comment: This subject is not very complex.  It seems to me FB (or some FB developer) could easily post a comprehensive chart displaying the browser action (show FB page vs. show "Sorry" page) for every possible combination of FB settings/values (viewer and viewee).  Not that I need one though.  You weren't aware that my page is a high school alumni page when you wrote your first answer.  Otherwise you probably wouldn't have made it sound like age and location are likely to affect my page specifically, which they aren't---not for us classmates anyway.  But thank you anyway---your answer did help!

Comment: my first answer is still there and correct about pages, i only added more information to it. i am just still not sure if you actually MEAN "page" when you say "page"...or if you mean a "user profile", which is a different thing...it is very simple for pages, you can either see it (even when you are not logged in) or the page is restricted by age or location. well...it could also be hidden, but then only admins would see it.

Comment: To my way of thinking, "user profile" isn't a very descriptive term to describe what I call my own personal "FB page," namely the page that a web browser loads when you enter the URL https://www.facebook.com/mathematrucker, but from what you're telling me it sounds like I should have been calling it that here on Stack Overflow.  My question has nothing to do with the "pages" that businesses etc. post on FB.

Comment: Now that we both know what I'm referring to, is my answer correct?  Based on my experiments, I ended up concluding that the "No" answer to the search engine question is the only thing that prevents a person's "user profile" as you call it (their "personal FB page," to my way of thinking) from being visible in a browser that isn't logged into FB.  And when a browser IS logged into FB, then everyone's "user profile" is visible regardless of how they answered that question.

Comment: By the way, in case this wasn't clear, my high school alumni "page" is just a page on the web, not any type of page on FB.

Comment: as a developer, you should always be as clear and detailed as possible. user profiles are not pages, just for the future. but yeah, in that case, it should be exactly that.

Comment: i´ve added a link to the privacy settings to my answer. now it´s pretty much valid for pages AND user profiles.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100302/discussion-between-mathematrucker-and-luschn).

Comment: what´s there to discuss? isn´t everything clear now?

Comment: (The only reason I went to chat was because Stack Overflow politely suggested it when I clicked "add a comment" at that point.  This is the first time I've ever carried on a comments-conversation like the one we've been having here, so I just went with it.)  Yes everything's clear now.  There is still a tad of doubt in my mind about whether there might be other settings (besides the search engine question) in a personal profile that could cause the "Sorry" page to appear, but you seem to have indicated there aren't.  I am content to go with that and not worry about this anymore.

Comment: Note (if you haven't already) that I have updated all three of my question, its title, and my answer.

Answer (score 1):

When clicked in a browser that isn't logged into a Facebook account, any link to the personal profile of a Facebook user who has answered "No" to the question "Do you want search engines outside of Facebook to link to your profile?" in their Privacy settings will take you to one of those "Sorry, this page isn't available" or "Sorry, this content isn't available right now" pages.

In other words, not only does a user's "No" answer to this question prevent search engines (other than Facebook's own) from linking to their personal profile, it also prevents every web page under the sun (besides Facebook) from linking to it (in browsers that are not logged into Facebook).

Comment: Might be making a mountain out of a molehill by pointing this out (for all I know, it could be ludicrously obvious to any FB programmer).  It's just that, as a non-FB-programmer, it took me awhile to figure out why I was getting the "Sorry" page.  So I figured there might be a few other non-FB-programmers out there who could benefit.